# Dynamically adding RecyclerViews to a LinearLayout does not increase the height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add many `RecyclerView`s dynamically to a `LinearLayout` depending upon the x coordinate of a 2-D array (Set). All the children of each view are not visible (it appears on scrolling the view).

In short, making the RecyclerView's height to `WRAP_CONTENT` is not stretching the height of `RecyclerView`.

I want all the children of all the RecyclerViews to be visible and not let any `RecyclerView` to be scrollable.

Following is the `table_layout` which I add dynamically:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Engine"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bid_report_label_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the `activity_main` layout of activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_bid_now"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:id="@+id/bike_image"
                android:onClick="startImageSlideshow"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_details"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I add `table_layout` to `activity_main` dynamically.

Please tell me how to make the `RecyclerView` `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Comment: It is simple bro . Don't use recycle view in scrollview . Just add your "row_layout" view in LinearLayout using for loop.

Comment: Your not understanding bro, the view has to be scrollable as it exceeds the screen size. And about the for loop thing, well its obvious and I'm doing that only.

Comment: What you doing only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `ScrollView`. Changing it to `NestedScrollView` solved the problem.